# oracle-sql Join two row have same id

Tags: oracle, join

How can I join two rows have same id to one row

```
id  name
1   abc
1   def
2   a
2   b
```

**I want result like that**

```
id name
1  abc
   def
2  a
   b
```

Comment: Your desired result has the same number of rows, but some are missing ids.

Comment: I interpreted that to be a carriage return between the values of name.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have two rows then the only tricky part is making sure that each row joins only to a different row, and that you do not get the same pair of rows back twice.

I would:

```
select a.name || chr(10) || b.name
from   table_a a join
       table_b b on (a.id    = b.id and 
                     a.rowid < b.rowid)
```